# Why is it called Anonymous Proxy?

Tags: account, proxy, signing, pallet-proxy

[Proxies](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-proxies) can be setup to sign specific or all (**any**) transactions on behalf of an account. You could say that the account is *proxied*, if it has a *proxy*.

There is a provision to create a keyless account which can be fully functional only when there is at least one proxy with **any** permissions to sign transactions on its behalf. This account (without a private key) is a *proxied* account. It is also not anonymous, as it is assigned a public key and can be traced on the blockchain.

Hence, it is neither *Anonymous* nor a *proxy*. Then why is it called an Anonymous Proxy?

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/7735

https://github.com/w3f/polkadot-wiki/issues/1458

Comment: My layman's guess is just because it has an unknown private key, it's anonymous in the sense, no one knows the key. I wouldn't be surprised if it's actually the correct answer lol.

Comment: Naming things is a very difficult thing in software development :P My interpretation is that it was a name used to describe the action, `let's create an "anonymous"(keyless) account and "proxy" it`(still not the best name for the action), but then it probably started being used as the name of the kind of account. As you've seen in the linked issue people agree is not the best name and should probably be changed. I guess it's just missing someone putting the work to actually change it

Comment: There has been a lot of discussion already about changing the name: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/7735

Happy to accept a PR

Comment: However, I dont think this is really an appropriate thread for StackExchange. It seems like you are asking for a feature request or API change, and not really looking for an answer to a question.

Comment: This is a FAQ in the community when it comes to proxies, hence added it here. Thought that having a thread on StackExchange would help understand the rationale and that there is an ongoing discussion to amend it @ShawnTabrizi Let me know how this question can be rephrased to be appropriate here

Comment: Yeah, I see why it's useful to ask because it's confusing but the only valid answer is "because the other of the pallet chose to call it that". I'm pretty sure everyone thinks it's a bad name. What other answer could you possibly expect?

Comment: I reiterate that this a frequently asked question in the community and would show up here one day or another. I would accept the answer "The author who wrote the pallet chose to call it that"